# Что такое js?

Tags: javascript

Я тут смотрю, что на хеш-коде есть метки javascript и js. Кто-нибудь может объяснить что это значит? Создается впечатление, что это одно и тоже. Однако, помнится мне книга весьма серьезного программиста (не помню автора), где он **кагбэ** намекал, что это - не совсем одно и то же. Насколько я  помню, js - это тесно связанная с IE технология, имеющая связь непосредственно с javascript, но не являющаяся таковой. Есть мысли на этот счет?

Comment: на SO js это алиас javascript, просто на хэшкоде нет меток. То о чем вы говорите, может быть как-то связано с историей но не с текущей реальностью, в текущей реальности весь браузерный javascript приводится к общему знаменателю, базирующемуся на стандарте ECMAscript,  в истории там был некий JS(именно так большими буквами) от M$, но я что-то плохо помню, но вообще сейчас для лицензионной безопасности наверное лучше использовать js,  т.к. 

>Название «JavaScript» является зарегистрированным товарным знаком компании Oracle Corporation.

Comment: @eicto, как все это было давно... но мы-то помним!)) Спасибо за коммент-ответ. Ответом не хотели бы сделать комментарий?

Comment: вам лучше самому покопать, у всех бывает ложная память, мало ли чего я тут придумал.

Comment: Вы не перепутали js и JScript -- диалект js от Microsoft? Там какие-то несовместимости были...

Comment: @alexlz, да, Елена Левина уже носом меня тыкнула. Спасибо за участие в исследовании! Действительно, так оно и есть

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вы, вероятно, имеете ввиду [JScript](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript), который похож на [JavaScript](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), но был реализован в [Internet Explorer](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer), во времена браузерной войны, в ответ на появившийся в браузере [Netscape Navigator](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_Navigator) `JavaScript`.

Формально, язык програмирования называется [ECMAScript](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), а JavaScript, JScript, [ActionScript](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) это различные реализации этого языка. Так получилось, что именно JavaScript включённый в Netscape Navigator стал наиболее известен и повелось все браузерные реализации ECMAScript называть JavaScript или сокращённо JS.